Why is my username userXXXX?
I went to my profile and saw that my username is userXXXX. Fortunately, when I clicked my other linked accounts, it's actually directed to my other accounts. Why is this name and the names of other accounts do not match?
By the way, I am new to this specific SE. I just saw this today, and I really am excited about the project. I recently graduated (in May 2014) with a BS in the Arts and Sciences (majoring Neuroscience, minoring Biology), so hopefully contributing to this project by reading more studies in the neurosciences can help me be more up-to-date on the knowledgebase. 

You can change your username by visiting your profile page on the main site and clicking the "Edit" link. If you just signed up for this site, you probably did not have a username here yet.
You can also copy your profile information (name included) from any of your other Stack Exchange sites. The profiles on each site are separate, but linked.
Your personal profile page on the main site is here: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/6223/user6223
